# Responsive Images on Heroku and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, responsive-design

What is the recommended method for implementing responsive images in a rails app hosted on Heroku?

I wanted to use [filamentgroup's Responsive-Images](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images) but I don't have htaccess on Heroku.

Comment: Why not just use pure css for responsive image resizing?